# download google drives files google drive api php v2

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using this function to download a file from google drive, it's working fine but it does not download anything, do I have to do anything else? This is the example that is on the site and that is working with me i wrote an echo in $httpRequest->getResponseBody(); and printed right,but what I do to download this?

```
$downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl(); 

if ($downloadUrl) {
    $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
    $httpRequest = $service->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
    if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
       return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
    } else {
      echo 'An error occurred';
      exit;
      return null;
    }
} else {
     echo'The file doesnt have any content stored on Drive';
     exit;
      return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if  `$httpRequest->getResponseBody();` is printing the data then why dont you just save it to a file?

```
$data = $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
file_put_contents("test.txt", data);
```

**Drive v3**

Google drive v3 has been out for more then two years you should consider updating your application.

You should consider following Googles Download tutorial [manage downloads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

```
 $fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
 $response = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array(
'alt' => 'media'));
 $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: I see that but i dont have this getBody, so I use this alternative mode which is also in a the documentation

Comment: If you dont have getBody then you need to update the client library you are using an old version or something there are more samples here [examples](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples)

Comment: yes,but look at this link https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get

Comment: Any reason you dont want to use the new version of Google drive api?

Comment: because I am limited in the version of PHP,my version is 5.3 and I cant change to 5.4(necessary version to the new version),because my site was molded in 5.3.

Comment: I was able to use this function that you mentioned but it returns it to me now

Comment: Call to a member function getBody() on a non-object

Comment: because you are running an old version of the Google drive API you are not going to see getBody().   you are going to have to do it the way you are doing now you just need to save the data as a file.

Comment: how I can save the data as a file?can you help me?

Comment: Did you try the first part of  my answer? file_put_contents("test.txt", data);